# Is it possible to add horizontal line to DistributionChart?

Tags: plotting

When comparing datasets using `DistributionChart`, is it possible to add a horizontal line to the chart that lies over all of the individual distributions within the chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GridLines`

```
SeedRandom@2; DistributionChart[
 RandomReal[BetaDistribution[2, 1/4], {2, 100}], 
 GridLines -> {None, {1}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness@2], 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for completness, and in case anyone has need for even more general additions: most chart and plot functions have the `Prolog` and `Epilog` options for exactly that. They are in some sense just a shortcut to the `Show` as in MeloaGo's answer, but they are quite handy to add litte things:

```
DistributionChart[
  RandomReal[BetaDistribution[2, 1/4], {2, 100}],
  Epilog -> {Line[{{0.5, 1}, {2.5, 1}}]}
]
```

[image: distribution chart with line drawn with epilog]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Show`:

```
dc = DistributionChart[
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, .5], {2, 100}]];
Show[dc, Graphics[Line[{{.5, 2}, {2.5, 2}}]]];
```

[image]